# Strange issue with Parse.com with key not being included

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

I'm having an issue very similar to this [one](https://www.parse.com/questions/using-includekey-on-ios-and-still-getting-has-no-data-error)

Basically I'm using Parse.com to load some objects, which have PFUser pointers, and then I'm also using includeKey to include those PFUsers, here's the code...

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"GameVillageObject"];

    [query whereKey:@"region" equalTo:[NSNumber numberWithInt:region]];
    [query includeKey:@"pfUser"];
    query.limit = 100;

    [sharedInstance requestSentWithDesc:@"Get all village objects in region"];

    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *PUObjects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            // The find succeeded.
            NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %d village objects from server.", PUObjects.count);

            if(PUObjects.count > 0)
            {
                villageObjects = PUObjects;

                for (int i=0; i<[villageObjects count]; i++)
                {

                    PFObject *villageItem = [villageObjects objectAtIndex:i];

                    PFUser *user = [villageItem objectForKey:@"pfUser"];

                    NSString *userName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[user objectForKey:@"username"]];

                    NSLog(@"User name is: %@.", userName);


                }


                [self setupVillageList];

                [sharedInstance centerImage:marketItemsContainer xChoice:YES yChoice:NO];

            }

        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            NSLog(@"Getting village objects Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);

        }
    }];
```

Now for some reason, everynow and again, maybe 1 time out of 10, the game is crashing, with this error

> Key "username" has no data. Call fetchIfNeeded before getting its
>   value.

Although I can't tell if it's crashing when I try to use "username" above, or a little later when I try to use "username" but either way, I don't get why most of the time it has no problem including those extra objects and then a few times it doesn't. Any ideas?

Comment: Please explain "or a little later when I try to use "username"...", as you haven't shown where you are using it and that might be where the error is.

Answer (score 13):

It sounds as though the associated `user` is not being loaded, but may be cached in most instances (and thus available). I can think of two ways to resolve this.

1) Call `fetchIfNeeded` as suggested by the error message:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"GameVillageObject"];

[query whereKey:@"region" equalTo:[NSNumber numberWithInt:region]];
[query includeKey:@"pfUser"];
...
  PFObject *villageItem = [villageObjects objectAtIndex:i];

  PFUser *user = [villageItem objectForKey:@"pfUser"];
  [user fetchIfNeeded];
  NSString *userName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[user objectForKey:@"username"]];

  NSLog(@"User name is: %@.", userName);
```

2) Specify `pfUser.username` in the `includeKey:` call

```
[query whereKey:@"region" equalTo:[NSNumber numberWithInt:region]];
[query includeKey:@"pfUser.username"];
query.limit = 100;
...
```

This should tell Parse to load `username` when the query is executed.

Comment: I saw the fetchIfNeeded but I wasn't sure if it needed a callback/block for it's result, and if not then I presume it blocks the main thread? which is not the end of the world but I wondered if there was a way to avoid that, for that reason maybe option 2 above might be the better way to go. Thanks.

Comment: Actually using the 2nd option gives the error "field username cannot be included because it is not a pointer to another object"

Comment: [user fetchIfNeeded]; is the answer for me! Thx

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem.

Here is what I did:

1. call fetchIfNeeded on the pointer.

ex.

```
[someObject.user fetchIfNeeded]
```

this will get the information about the user that you need.

2. If you need a PFFile from the user object you can do the following.

//if you run this code in cellForRowAtIndexPath and want to update the profile image for the user you can do the following.

```
User *user = (User *)someObject.user;

 [user.profileImage getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {

        if (!error) {

            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];



            cell.userProfileImage.image = image;
        }else{
            NSLog(@"Print error!!! %@", error.localizedDescription);
        }


    }];
```